# In Atwood machine, does the tension of the rope do work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, string

It seems in all Atwood machine exercises I can find, no one ever takes into account the tension of the rope when solving with conservation of energy. Why is this? Shouldn't the tension be a non-conservative force contributing to the net work?

Comment: Depends on what particular subsystem you're looking at. The tension does work on each of the blocks, but since it's an internal force, it does no work on the Atwood machine as a whole.

Comment: Cool, I've upgraded my comment to an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what particular subsystem you're looking at. The tension does work on each of the blocks, but since it's an internal force, it does no work on the Atwood machine as a whole.